# What is the difference between a plenary and a keynote talk?

Tags: conference, presentation, workshop

I am organizing a workshop and have invited a featured speaker to give a synthetic talk. What is the appropriate term for this role?

Comment: "Synthetic talk"?

Answer (score 15):

They are both used (often interchangeably in my field). A plenary is a talk which does not have anything scheduled against it. A keynote is an invited talk in a conference or session.

Answer (score 9):

I came up with this answer while asking the question:

Both terms indicate a sort of synthesis, but [plenary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/plenary) seems to refer to being fully attended whereas [keynote](http://www.wordnik.com/words/keynote) appears to indicate setting a common theme.

Answer (score -1):

Keynote; A theme by an authority person with credentials on topic and knoledge of participants and their reason for being here. Speaker offers challenges.
Plenary; Speaker/ Facilitator with authority remarks to stimulate input and discussion by all to come to conclusion for action.